# WP - Retraiving child pages of current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've some cpt post that depend from a partent CPT. I want to retrieve the child cpt from the current parent cpt, but this code retrieves all the pages within the cpt (other parents and childs too). What is wrong?

```
if (is_singular('conversacion-ingles')) {
    remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');
    add_action('genesis_loop',  'show_all_children');


    function show_all_children(){

        $child_args = array(
            'post_parent' => $post->ID, // The parent id.
            'post_type'   => 'conversacion-ingles',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order'       => 'ASC'
        );

        $children = get_children( $child_args );
        if ( empty($children) ) return;


        echo '<div class="children">';
        echo '<ul class="children level-'.$current_level.'-children">';

        foreach ($children as $child) {

            echo '<li>';

            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($child->ID).'">';
            echo get_the_title($child->ID);
            echo '</a>';

            echo '</li>';

            }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: May want to look into [get_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) instead as it has more fine-tuning capabilities. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/getting-only-direct-child-pages-in-wordpress-with-get-pages

Comment: ok, it works, thanks. Both 'child of' and 'parent' are needed.